# using a list of regressors and storing the values of betas

Tags: list, regression, storage, stata

I have a list of circumstances and effects:
I want to generate a matrix with betas containing the values of betas. I am going to run the loop 10 times, because i am in fact going to bootstrap my observations.

So far I have tried:

```
local circumstances height weight

local effort training diet

foreach i in 1 10 {

    reg outcome  `circumstances' `effects' 

    * store in column i the values of betas of circumstances

    * store in column i the values of betas of effort 

 }
```

Does anyone know what should the code look like in order to store those values?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pseudocode would first store in "column 1" the first lot of betas and then overwrite them (column 1) with the second lot of betas. Then it would do the same again for column 10 with the first lot of betas and the second lot of betas. That is a long way from anything that makes sense. Nothing in your pseudocode takes bootstrap samples from the dataset, although perhaps you are intending to add code for that later.

Stata doesn't really work with any idea of column numbers, although the idea makes sense to Mata.

Unless there are very specific reasons -- which you would need to spell out -- there is no need to write your own code *ab initio* for bootstrapping, as the whole point of `bootstrap` is to do that for you.

Here is complete code for a reproducible example of bootstrapping a silly regression:

```
sysuse auto, clear
bootstrap b_weight=_b[weight] b_price=_b[price] , reps(1000) seed(2803) : regress mpg weight price
```

See also the help for `bootstrap` to learn about its other options, including `saving()`.

10 repetitions would be regarded as absurdly small for the number of bootstrap samples.